# Adding a New Quartz.NET Job

Tags: quartz.net

I've inherited an application which uses Quartz.NET

I have no idea how to maintain/use this and need to add a new Job.

I created a new `Job` class and added it to the jobs xml file as an element under `<schedule>`.

Will this automatically add the appropriate row to the CRON_TRIGGERS table?
Or is there some other step?
Or do I need to manually insert a row into the CRON_TRIGGERS table?

Thanks

Comment: Why close? Why downvote? No explanation? Cat got your tongue?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new job by using something like

```
var jobBuilder = new JobBuilder.Create<IJob>()
                               .SetJobDataMap(jobDataMap)
                               .Build();
```

`IJob` will be a class that will be derived from the `IJob` interface. The `JobDataMap` can be instantiated with a dictionary with the given data. You can retrieve the data from the IJob Execute method with something like  `IJobExecutionContext.JobDetail.JobDataMap["aKeyInYourDictionary"]`

Now you'll have to set a trigger to run the job every x milliseconds.

```
var triggerBuilder = new TriggerBuilder.Create().StartNow().WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithInterval(timeInMilliSeconds).RepeatForever());
```

Finally use the `IScheduler.ScheduleJob(jobBuilder, triggerBuilder)` to schedule the job.

Comment: @Prasanthe Thanks, but that will not work in the architecture of this application. It uses xml to schedule jobs and runs as a windows service. It gets the jobs like this `nameValueCollection[QuartzPluginXmlFilenamesKey] = @"~\Jobs.xml";` and passes `nameValueCollection` into StdSchedulerFactory like this `ISchedulerFactory stdSchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(nameValueCollection);`